# GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY causes flicker

Tags: android, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

As already mentioned this line of code

```
setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
```

causes my application to flicker weardly.
That means if I changed it to

```
setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

it stops flickering.

The device I am on is a ASUS Padfone a86.

Do you have ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities: the OS is doing something wrong, or your app is doing something wrong.

If you don't see flicker in any other apps or system animations, it's unlikely to be the system at fault.  You don't really describe the nature of the flicker, but there are a couple of common problems.

One possibility is that you're not fully redrawing the screen every time the `onDrawFrame()` is called.  If you don't, the system will show a blank or previously-rendered frame.  Another possibility is that you're updating state while `onDrawFrame()` is executing, so you're getting a frame with a partial update that leaves objects in strange places.

Of course, if you're getting the results you want with `RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY`, you may want to just stick with it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Setting the it to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY is no option in my case. Could you explain how to explicitly redraw the whole screen because i am very new to OpenGL.

Comment: Start with `glClear()` and draw everything.  Using `GLSurfaceView`, you don't have the option of returning from `onDrawFrame()` without drawing.

Comment: glClear(...) works for me. Thank you very much. Didn't think it could be that easy. ^^

Comment: Cool.  You may want to look at https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/ as an example.  It's a very simple game, but it's based on `GLSurfaceView` and it exercises all the basic features.